# Qt on RaspberryPi - QXmlAttributes implicit declaration

Tags: c++, linux, qt, raspberry-pi

I am building Qt on RaspberryPi using host desktop following this guide https://wiki.qt.io/Raspberry_Pi_Beginners_Guide.

And when it comes to building Qt with `make` command i got a strange error:

```
In file included from ../../include/QtXml/qxml.h:1:0,
         from dom/qdom.cpp:54:
../../include/QtXml/../../src/xml/sax/qxml.h:121:5: error: function ‘QXmlAttributes::QXmlAttributes(QXmlAttributes&&)’ defaulted on its first declaration with an exception-specification that differs from the implicit declaration ‘QXmlAttributes::QXmlAttributes(QXmlAttributes&&)’
Makefile:1338: recipe for target '.obj/qdom.o' failed
make[2]: *** [.obj/qdom.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/anon/opt/qt5/qtbase/src/xml'
Makefile:295: recipe for target 'sub-xml-make_first' failed
make[1]: *** [sub-xml-make_first] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/anon/opt/qt5/qtbase/src'
Makefile:46: recipe for target 'sub-src-make_first' failed
make: *** [sub-src-make_first] Error 2
```

Some specification:
Host - Debian Jessie
RPI - Raspbian

What should I do now? Restarting installation from beginning gives nothing.

Answer (score 2):

The first error apparently is resulted from a conflict in the declaration of "QXmlAttributes::QXmlAttributes(QXmlAttributes&&)"

I had the same error :  **function ‘QXmlAttributes::QXmlAttributes(QXmlAttributes&&)’ defaulted on its first declaration with an exception-specification that differs from the implicit declaration ‘QXmlAttributes::QXmlAttributes(QXmlAttributes&&)’**

I managed to solve this by following rocommendations from the following link : [Cross compiling for Raspberry Error](https://forum.qt.io/topic/73194/cross-compiling-for-raspberry-error/7)

The solution is to change :

1.Open the /qt5/qtbase/src/xml/sax/qxml.h file

2.Change : **"QXmlAttributes(QXmlAttributes &&) Q_DECL_NOTHROW = default"**

to   **"QXmlAttributes(QXmlAttributes &&) = default"**

Hope this helps !